# how to make all of the sliders in one vertical line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have a form that includes a label, slider and an output.
Different sizes of labels can mess the vertical organization of the slider (like in the link below).
[dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLVVZ.jpg)

This is my code:

```
function slider(name,item){
    var label=document.createElement("label");
    label.innerHTML = name+" rate for "+item;
    
    var form=document.createElement("form");
    form.name="registrationForm";
    form.className ="mainForm";
    
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type="range";
    input.name="ageInputName";
    input.id="input"+name+item;
    input.value="50";
    input.min="0";

    var output = document.createElement("output");
    output.name="ageOutputName";
    output.id="output"+name+item;

    input.oninput=()=>updateTextInput(input.id,output.id);

    form.appendChild(label);
    form.appendChild(input);
    form.appendChild(output);
    output.value="50";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(form);

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please add html code.

Comment: The picture in the link didn't paint the picture, can you please upload the html codes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css classes with attributes width and display:inline-block to achieve what you are looking for. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aycx341s/)
In your javascript you can use `input.classList.add('input');`

HTML

```
.label {
  width:150px;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
.input {
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.output {
  width:50px;
  background:#d7d7d7;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

-- if it has to be done in js you can always [add styles in js](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) to your elements

JS

```
slider('first', 'bag');
slider('second', 'box');
slider('third', 'floor');

function slider(name, item) {
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.innerHTML = name + " rate for " + item;
  label.classList.add("label");

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.name = "registrationForm";
  form.className = "mainForm";

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "range";
  input.name = "ageInputName";
  input.id = "input" + name + item;
  input.value = "50";
  input.min = "0";
  input.classList.add('input');

  var output = document.createElement("output");
  output.name = "ageOutputName";
  output.id = "output" + name + item;
  output.classList.add('output');

  input.oninput = () => updateTextInput(input.id, output.id);

  form.appendChild(label);
  form.appendChild(input);
  form.appendChild(output);
  output.value = "50";
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(form);

}
```

For a slightly more advanced method you could learn about [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).